# How to toggle tab navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get navigation tabs to toggle content based on it's tab selected but content is not toggling and all content is being displayed and not hidden on default.

I have tried onclick=showBody("tabid") with no luck.

Right now code is as follows;

```
<section class="border-black">
    <div class="container sr-subresults-nav">
        <ul class="sr-navigation">
        <li class="sr-subnav-item" onclick=showBody("bridgerectifiers")>Bridge Rectifiers</li>
        <li class="sr-subnav-item" onclick=showBody("limitingdiodes")>Limiting Diodes</li>
        <li class="sr-subnav-item" onclick=showBody("sfrecovery")><a class="sr-nav-link" href="">SF Recovery</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<section class="pt-1 mb-0 border-black">
    <div id="product-results">
        <div id="bridgerectifiers" class="search-result-products">
            <div class="diodes-rectifiers-content" id="bridge-rectifiers-diodes-filter-div">
                <h6>Bridge Rectifiers</h6>
                content for bridge rectifiers goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="limitingdiodes" class="search-result-products">
            <div class="diodes-rectifiers-content" id="current-limiting-diodes-filter-div">
                <h6>Current Limiting Diodes</h6>
                content for current limiting diodes goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sfrecovery" class="search-result-products">
            <div class="diodes-rectifiers-content" id="super-fast-recovery-diodes-filter-div">
                <h6>Super Fast Recovery Diodes</h6>
                content for super fast recovery diodes goes here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
function showBody(item) {
    hideBody();
    if (item == "bridgerectifiers") {
    $("#bridgerectifiers").show();
    $("#bridgerectifiers").hidden = false;
}
    if (item == "limitingdiodes") {
    $("#limitingdiodes").show();
    $("#limitingdiodes").hidden = false;
    }
};

    function hideBody() {
    $("#bridgerectifiers").hide();
    $("#bridgerectifiers").hidden = false;
    $("#limitingdiodes").hide();
    $("#limitingdiodes").hidden = false;
}
```

Would like to get all content hidden on default and the tab selected to show the content related to that tab while all other content is hidden or not displayed. New to js and jquery so open to other options other than onclick.

Comment: Where is css and js? If you can add code we can help with that. Because by default if you want to hide add css property display none and remember to add position absolute if you are just using opacity

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added the Javascript that I have been trying to use but still new to JS so I'm sure it doesn't look good. Would I still need CSS if I am using Javascript to try and show/hide/toggle?

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your html file?

Comment: Yes if you want it to be hidden by default just use .search-result-products{ display:none} and in script you can just use siblings function to hide others and show the clicked one.

Comment: Instead of using if simply use this https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ and say $('#'+item).siblings().hide(); $('#'+item).show();

Answer (score 0):

In hideBody() function, you should remove `$("#bridgerectifiers").hidden = false;` and `$("#limitingdiodes").hidden = false;`.
They're code to show elements again.

You can also remove `$("#bridgerectifiers").hidden = false;` and `$("#limitingdiodes").hidden = false;` from `showBody()` function because they do same as `$("#bridgerectifiers").show();`.

Or you just use the following code.

```js
function showBody(item) {
    hideBody();
    $("#" + item).show();
};

function hideBody() {
    $(".search-result-products").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="border-black">
    <div class="container sr-subresults-nav">
        <ul class="sr-navigation">
            <li class="sr-subnav-item" onclick='showBody("bridgerectifiers")'>Bridge Rectifiers</li>
            <li class="sr-subnav-item" onclick='showBody("limitingdiodes")'>Limiting Diodes</li>
            <li class="sr-subnav-item" onclick='showBody("sfrecovery")'>SF Recovery</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="pt-1 mb-0 border-black">
    <div id="product-results">
        <div id="bridgerectifiers" class="search-result-products">
            <div class="diodes-rectifiers-content" id="bridge-rectifiers-diodes-filter-div">
                <h6>Bridge Rectifiers</h6>
                content for bridge rectifiers goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="limitingdiodes" class="search-result-products">
            <div class="diodes-rectifiers-content" id="current-limiting-diodes-filter-div">
                <h6>Current Limiting Diodes</h6>
                content for current limiting diodes goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sfrecovery" class="search-result-products">
            <div class="diodes-rectifiers-content" id="super-fast-recovery-diodes-filter-div">
                <h6>Super Fast Recovery Diodes</h6>
                content for super fast recovery diodes goes here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```